Redis. Добавить новое поле во все записи JSON с определенным ключом, где ещё нет этого нового поля
В процесса работы над новой задачей понадобилось добавить в один из ключей в Redis новое поле и заполнить его каким-нибудь дефолтным значением. Например, был вот такой JSON:
{
"x":"xxxx",
"y":"yyyy",
"z":"zzzz"
}

Я кое-что поменял сущность, и новый JSON выглядит вот так:
{
"x":"xxxx",
"y":"yyyy",
"z":"zzzz",
"c":"cccc"
}

Новые записи стали добавляться, но мне нужно привести Redis к единообразию, т.е. добавить новое поле в каждую запись, где этого поля нет и заполнить это поле каким-нибудь дефолтным значением.
Не очень силён в Redis и NoSQL, так что заранее извиняюсь, если где-то неточно сформулировал вопрос. Заранее спасибо!
